# How to fix XOpenDisplay Failed

Tags: ubuntu, root, xming

I have Windows 10. I installed Ubuntu and when I want to run root at the Ubuntu Prompt I get this error:

```
PopupLogo, XOpenDisplay failed
   ------------------------------------------------------------
  | Welcome to ROOT 6.18/02                  https://root.cern |
  |                               (c) 1995-2019, The ROOT Team |
  | Built for linuxx8664gcc on Sep 05 2019, 00:50:00           |
  | From tag , 23 August 2019                                  |
  | Try '.help', '.demo', '.license', '.credits', '.quit'/'.q' |
   ------------------------------------------------------------

root [0]
```

I have Xming installed on my desktop however I still get the above error. Is there a way to fix this easily?
I think this is effecting how I use ROOT. For example when I want to create a simple histogram (from an exponential function), everything runs fine to the next line but I do not get a histogram graph out. I do not think there is anything wrong with the code since I got it from a user manual and root doesn't show any errors but it just does show the histogram. Thanks!

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu in place of Windows, or did you install it from the "Ubuntu on Windows" Windows app?

Answer (score -1):

Put the following command in terminal before running.

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

Comment: Is there nothing else they need to do from an XMing perspective?